# Plot Pandas Dataframe with Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with a datetime index and column of scores.

```
Pandas Dataframe
Index              Score
2016-09-01          5
2016-09-15          6
.
2017-01-05          3
.
2017-12-24          2
```

How can I with seaborn:

(1) box plot the scores grouped by month such that the x-axis is continuous from the earliest date (Sep 2016) to the latest date (Dec 2017).

(2) line plot the mean score each month such that:

(a) the x-axis reflects the months and there are 2 line plots representing the years 2016 and 2017.

(b) the x-axis is continuous from the earliest date (Sep 2016) to the latest date (Dec 2017) with a single line plot.

I have tried searching for the answers, going down the path of groupby pandas objects but couldn't quite find it. Thanks for any advice.

EDIT:

I tried seaborn.pointplot(x=df.index.month, y=df) and seaborn.boxplot(x=df.index.month, y=df) and it gave me the below.

This is wrong as the x-tick '12' data actually belongs to the year 2016 and should show to the left of the rest of the x-ticks which are from 2017. Obviously this is because I used .index.month which doesn't discriminate the year but I couldn't find other ways to do this. Also, do the point values represent the mean cos I evidently did not pass in a mean function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what trouble did you encounter?